# How can i catch a query error message when using UNIQUE for a field in DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on insert form values into DB. I want to know how to print an error message if a value already exists in db when setted this field to unique. Here is the db table design

```
id(PRIMARY KEY auto_increment) name(char) email(UNIQUE) password(char) date
```

**Here is there insert code:**

```
try {
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_registration SET 
        nom=:nom,
        prenom=:prenom,
        email=:email,
        password=:password,
        sexe=:sexe,
        regis_date=CURDATE()";

 $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 $s->bindValue(':nom', $_POST['nom']); 

 $s->bindValue(':prenom', $_POST['prenom']);

 $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);

 $s->bindValue(':password', password_hash($_POST['pwd1'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

 $s->bindvalue(':sexe', $_POST['sexe']);

 $s->execute();

if ($s) {
  echo "insert good";
  exit();
}
  } catch (PDOException $e) 
  {
    $errorinsert='Error inserting values';
    include_once'error_page.html.php';
    exit();
  }
```

The insert part works great...But how i can print the error message if the email already exists in db

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how do you catch the error, you can do it with `$e->getMessage()`

```
 try {
  //code
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
   $errorinsert = $e->getMessage();
   include_once'error_page.html.php';
   exit();
 }
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php